# Windows Azure runtime 2.5 cannot be found

Tags: c#, windows, azure, sdk, cloud

This is the error from Windows Event Viewer.

```
The description for Event ID 1007 from source Windows Azure Runtime 2.5.0.0 cannot be found.Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

1540
WaIISHost
Failed to load role assembly: Scheduler.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

Here are my assembly redirections:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ServiceBus" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I've verfied and my bin folder server side contais scheduler.webservice dll and also azure.serviceruntime 2.5

Anyone has a clue on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found this was because I had not set the Entry Point in the service definition file (.csdef). This resulted in an `__entrypoint.txt` file being created for the role when calling `cspack.exe`. I then was able to successfully call `csrun.exe`.

This is what I was missing from my service definition file:

```
  <Runtime>
      <EntryPoint>
          <NetFxEntryPoint assemblyName="MyAzureWorker.dll" />
      </EntryPoint>
  </Runtime>
```